# SQL Alchemy: AttributeError: type object 'events' has no attribute 'query'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to delete events in the database that already happened. My script is as follows.

On the line with **, I get an error

```
AttributeError: type object 'events' has no attribute 'query'
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks!

```
Base = automap_base()

# engine, suppose it has two tables 'user' and 'address' set up
engine = create_engine("DB_URL")

# reflect the tables
Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)

# mapped classes are now created with names by default
# matching that of the table name.
Event = Base.classes.events
User = Base.classes.users

**events = Event.query.filter(end_time < datetime.now())**
session = Session(engine)
session.delete(events)
session.commit()
```

Answer (score 8):

You don't call `query()` on your mapped classes, you call `query()` on your `session` object:

```
Base = automap_base()

# engine, suppose it has two tables 'user' and 'address' set up
engine = create_engine("DB_URL")

# reflect the tables
Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)

# mapped classes are now created with names by default
# matching that of the table name.
Event = Base.classes.events
User = Base.classes.users

session = Session(engine)
selected_events = session.query(Event).filter(Event.end_time < datatime.now())
selected_events.delete()
session.commit()
```

Comment: Your solution didn't work, but I could come up with the right solution thanks to your code.

`session.query(Event).filter(Event.end_time < datetime.now()).delete()`
did the job!

Comment: Cheers, I might edit my answer to reflect this. I forgot you need to call `delete` on the selection object.